# PostHogs onFeatureFlags callback function being called multiple times

Tags: angular, callback, feature-flags, posthog

I'm working on an Angular application feature where upon selecting a role, the user has a 50% chance to be redirected to screen A or screen B, determined through a feature flag. My issue is that posthog.onFeatureFlags is getting called multiple times even though the role selection logic seems to trigger only once.

```
// in template
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">
      <app-role-card
        (click)="onRoleSelected(role.role, role.roleValue)"
      >
      </app-role-card>
    </div>

// in ts file
onRoleSelected(role: Role, roleValue: RoleValue): void {
    this.postHogService.sendEvent(eventNames.slp_signup_roleSelectionComplete_NW00, {
      $set: { up_signup_profile_role: role },
      ep_roleSelected: role,
    });
    console.log('roles selected');

    posthog.onFeatureFlags(() => {
      console.log('onfeature flag called I am in designation comp');
      const relevantFeatureFlag = this.roleToFeatureFlagMap[role];
      const featureFlagPayload = getFeatureFlag(relevantFeatureFlag)
      const destinationRoute = this.getDestinationRoute();
      this.router.navigate([destinationRoute]);
    });
  }
```

1. I see roles selected logged only once.
2. The event slp_signup_roleSelectionComplete_NW00 is triggered once.
3. However, onfeature flag called I am in designation comp gets logged multiple times as shown in this screenshot:
   [The logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vFAD.png)

for more context there is also another selection screen after this and when the user selects an option on that screen, `onfeatureflag called I am in designation comp` is logged again even though I am not calling `posthog.onFeatureFlags` in that component. This suggests that the posthog.onFeatureFlags in the `designation` component is being re-invoked.
Heres is how posthog is setup in the project

main.ts

```
import { init as initPostHog } from './app/shared/postHog/posthog';

initPostHog();
```

in posthog.ts

```
export function onFeatureFlags(cb: any): void {
  posthog.onFeatureFlags(cb);
}

export function init(): void {
  posthog.init(environment.POSTHOG_API_KEY, {
    api_host: environment.POSTHOG_API_HOST,
   });
}

export function getFeatureFlag(label: string): string | boolean | undefined {
  return posthog.getFeatureFlag(label);
}


export function capture(eventName: string, eventData: any): void {
  if (!environment.cs) {
    posthog.capture(eventName, eventData);
  }
}
```

Any pointers on whats wrong here.

I have tried changing the detection strategy but it didn't work.
Calling the feature flags in the constructor or ngOnInit works and the function is only called once but I dont want to call multiple feature flags (one for each role) on every render and only want to call the relevant feature flag once a role is selected.
I want `posthog.onFeatureFlags` to be only called once since I need to redirect the user, and if its called again at a later stage the user gets redirected again.
How do I stop it from being called again?